# How to get confidence bands for every monthly returns in R?

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval

I have a list of managers that provide monthly returns like below:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
View(edhec)
```

I'm NOT running a regression nor forecasting. The goal is to provide more context around the monthly returns. And I'm thinking about using confidence bands. For example, the `Convertible Arbitrage` manager returned `0.0315` on `8/31/2009`. With confidence bands, I would be able to say that with a certain confidence level, this return is whether within the intervals or not. I'd like to have the bands for every return.

Most of the information I found was about plotting a time series with confidence intervals, but I'd like to add two columns to each manager with `lower` and `upper` band numbers. Here is my approach:

1. Setting a confidence level, say 95%. This means alpha = 0.05 (`qnorm(.975)`or `qnorm(.025)` ).
2. Get cumulative mean for every row in a column. I've tried `cummean` from `dplyr` but all the means are stored in a list (`cummean(edhec)`).
3. Calculate the margin of error: `qnorm(.975)`*(cumulative standard deviation / sqrt(cumulative number of rows).
4. The `lower` and `upper` bands will be cumulative mean +/- margin of error.

I think this probably requires advanced loop skills and mine is very basic. Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you are expecting a CI around a single observation and you don't appear to have any statistical basis for establishing a standard deviation for a single observation. I think you need to hire a consultant who understands statistics. (Hiring a consultant to fill in the gaps in your business methods education should be a pretty standard procedure.)

Comment: Thanks @42. I'm not trying to get a single CI or a standard deviation for a single observation. Instead, I'm trying to see where the most recent value falls given historical returns. That's why I'm using cumulative mean in step 2 and cumulative standard deviation in step 3.

Comment: Without data, your description of the algorithm will remain ambiguous. I obviously misinterpreted your problem description, but perhaps others did as well since you got not takers. You are much more likely to get a response if you post data and your efforts at coding.

Comment: My data set is very similar to the `edhec` mentioned in my post. To get cumulative means, I've tried `cummean` from `dplyr`. It works fine but the problem is that the results are stored as a list of numbers rather than a data frame (See Step 2). The other problem is I'm not sure what would be the best way to get cumulative standard deviations in Step 3.